# How to skip and execute the VBA macros without misapplied styles?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I havie a few macros for applying styles in word document then find and replace the given styles to HTML tags. I am getting an error when I run the macro:

> "Run time error:5941 The requested member of collection does not
>   exist."

For example: In the code below, I have applied all the styles except the `Book_Title` style.

How can I skip the missing styles when I run the macros?

```
Sub HTML_Conversion()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Image")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<p align=""center""><img src=""images\chapter_img.jpg"" alt=""""/></p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Book_Title")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = _
            "<h1 class=""book-title"">^&</h1>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Half_Title")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""halftitle"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Indent_Para")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""indent"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NonIndent_Para")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""noindent"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

As you said, I have tried in my macros, but i am getting the same error.

My full codes are below:

```
    Sub HTML_Conversion()

    Dim sStyleName As String

    sStyleName = "HTML_Start"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = _
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>^p<!DOCTYPE html>^p<html xml:lang=""en-US"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">^p<head>^p<title></title>^p<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""../css/epub.css""/>^p</head>^p<body>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If

    sStyleName = "Ack_title"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""act-title"">^&</p>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
    sStyleName = "FigCaption"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "^p<figure>^p<img src=""images\chapter_img.jpg"" alt=""""/>^p<figcaption>^&</figcaption></figure>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "TabCaption"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""tabcaption"">^&</p>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "ListItem"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<li>^&</li>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "OL_Start"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<ol>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "OL_End"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "</ol>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "UL_Start"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<ul>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "UL_End"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "</ul>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Image"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<p align=""center""><img src=""images\chapter_img.jpg"" alt=""""/></p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
    sStyleName = "Book_Title"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = _
            "<h1 class=""book-title"">^&</h1>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Half_Title"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""halftitle"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


        End If
    sStyleName = "Indent_Para"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""indent"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "NonIndent_Para"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""noindent"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    End If
    sStyleName = "Book_Author"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""bookauthor"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Pub"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""pub"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Pub1"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""pub1"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Copyright"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""copyright"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Section"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""section"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Center_Para"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""center"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Block_Quote"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""blockquote"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Poem"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""poem"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Poem1"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""poem1"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Bibliography"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""bib"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Index"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""index"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Notes_Titles"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""nt"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If
    sStyleName = "Notes"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""notes"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    End If
    sStyleName = "Right_Para"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""right"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    End If
    sStyleName = "Chapter_Title"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "<p class=""chtitle"">^&</p>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    End If
    sStyleName = "H1"
    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "<h1>^&</h1>^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End If

    MsgBox "HTML CONVERSION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY"

        End Sub
```

Comment: Please see my edit for the solution to your second problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basic error-handling: check if the style is valid before using it!

There are several ways to do this, one is to loop all styles to see if the name matches one of the available styles. Also, put it in a function so you can reuse it. In my example, the function is called `IsValidDocumentStyle`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HTML_Conversion()

    Dim sStyleName As String

    sStyleName = "Book_Title"

    If IsValidDocumentStyle(ActiveDocument, sStyleName) Then
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(sStyleName)
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = _
                "<h1 class=""book-title"">^&</h1>^p"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If

End Sub

Function IsValidDocumentStyle(poDoc As Document, psStyleName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oStyle As Style
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    bReturn = False

    For Each oStyle In poDoc.Styles
        If oStyle.NameLocal = psStyleName Then
            bReturn = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    IsValidDocumentStyle = bReturn

    Set oStyle = Nothing
End Function
```

**EDIT**:

When trying to use my example, you are passing the style name `"HTML_Start"` to `IsValidDocumentStyle` but then use the literal string `"sStyleName"` as the style name in the lines `Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sStyleName")`.